# Unable to get VMware shared folders working in Ubuntu 14.10 guest

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vmware-workstation

I installed Ubuntu 14.10 64-bit in VMWare Workstation 10.0.5 running in Windows 8.1 Enterprise. I installed VMware tools by running the vmware-install.pl script in the terminal, but I am getting an error running this script:

```
Installing VMware Tools.

In which directory do you want to install the binary files? 
[/usr/bin] 

What is the directory that contains the init directories (rc0.d/ to rc6.d/)? 
[/etc] 

What is the directory that contains the init scripts? 
[/etc/init.d] 

In which directory do you want to install the daemon files? 
[/usr/sbin] 

In which directory do you want to install the library files? 
[/usr/lib/vmware-tools] 

The path "/usr/lib/vmware-tools" does not exist currently. This program is 
going to create it, including needed parent directories. Is this what you want?
[yes] yes

In which directory do you want to install the documentation files? 
[/usr/share/doc/vmware-tools] 

The path "/usr/share/doc/vmware-tools" does not exist currently. This program 
is going to create it, including needed parent directories. Is this what you 
want? [yes] yes

The installation of VMware Tools 9.6.4 build-2441333 for Linux completed 
successfully. You can decide to remove this software from your system at any 
time by invoking the following command: "/usr/bin/vmware-uninstall-tools.pl".

Before running VMware Tools for the first time, you need to configure it by 
invoking the following command: "/usr/bin/vmware-config-tools.pl". Do you want 
this program to invoke the command for you now? [yes] yes

Initializing...


Making sure services for VMware Tools are stopped.

Stopping VMware Tools services in the virtual machine:
   Guest operating system daemon:                                      done
   VMware User Agent (vmware-user):                                    done
   Blocking file system:                                               done
   Unmounting HGFS shares:                                             done
   Guest filesystem driver:                                            done
Stopping Thinprint services in the virtual machine:
   Stopping Virtual Printing daemon:                                   done


update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
The module vmci has already been installed on this system by another installer 
or package and will not be modified by this installer.

The module vsock has already been installed on this system by another installer
or package and will not be modified by this installer.

The module vmxnet3 has already been installed on this system by another 
installer or package and will not be modified by this installer.

The module pvscsi has already been installed on this system by another 
installer or package and will not be modified by this installer.

The module vmmemctl has already been installed on this system by another 
installer or package and will not be modified by this installer.

The VMware Host-Guest Filesystem allows for shared folders between the host OS 
and the guest OS in a Fusion or Workstation virtual environment.  Do you wish 
to enable this feature? [yes] yes


Before you can compile modules, you need to have the following installed... 

make
gcc
kernel headers of the running kernel


Searching for GCC...
Detected GCC binary at "/usr/bin/gcc".
The path "/usr/bin/gcc" appears to be a valid path to the gcc binary.
Would you like to change it? [no] no

Searching for a valid kernel header path...
Detected the kernel headers at "/lib/modules/3.16.0-23-generic/build/include".
The path "/lib/modules/3.16.0-23-generic/build/include" appears to be a valid 
path to the 3.16.0-23-generic kernel headers.
Would you like to change it? [no] no

make: Entering directory '/tmp/modconfig-JgQ1bK/vmhgfs-only'
Using 2.6.x kernel build system.
/usr/bin/make -C /lib/modules/3.16.0-23-generic/build/include/.. SUBDIRS=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
  MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-23-generic'
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-JgQ1bK/vmhgfs-only/backdoorGcc64.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-JgQ1bK/vmhgfs-only/message.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-JgQ1bK/vmhgfs-only/dir.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-JgQ1bK/vmhgfs-only/request.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-JgQ1bK/vmhgfs-only/hgfsUtil.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-JgQ1bK/vmhgfs-only/cpName.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-JgQ1bK/vmhgfs-only/link.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-JgQ1bK/vmhgfs-only/rpcout.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-JgQ1bK/vmhgfs-only/stubs.o
/tmp/modconfig-JgQ1bK/vmhgfs-only/link.c: In function ‘HgfsReadlink’:
/tmp/modconfig-JgQ1bK/vmhgfs-only/link.c:186:10: error: implicit declaration of function ‘vfs_readlink’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
          error = vfs_readlink(dentry, buffer, buflen, fileName);
          ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:257: recipe for target '/tmp/modconfig-JgQ1bK/vmhgfs-only/link.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/tmp/modconfig-JgQ1bK/vmhgfs-only/link.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Makefile:1345: recipe for target '_module_/tmp/modconfig-JgQ1bK/vmhgfs-only' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/tmp/modconfig-JgQ1bK/vmhgfs-only] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-23-generic'
Makefile:130: recipe for target 'vmhgfs.ko' failed
make: *** [vmhgfs.ko] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/tmp/modconfig-JgQ1bK/vmhgfs-only'

The filesystem driver (vmhgfs module) is used only for the shared folder 
feature. The rest of the software provided by VMware Tools is designed to work 
independently of this feature.

If you wish to have the shared folders feature, you can install the driver by 
running vmware-config-tools.pl again after making sure that gcc, binutils, make
and the kernel sources for your running kernel are installed on your machine. 
These packages are available on your distribution's installation CD.
[ Press Enter key to continue ]
```

My Linux kernel version is 3.16.0-23.31. How I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This helped me

```
cd /usr/lib/vmware-tools/modules/source
sudo tar xf vmhgfs.tar
grep -q d_u.d_alias vmhgfs-only/inode.c && echo "already patched" && exit 0
sudo sed -i -e s/d_alias/d_u.d_alias/ vmhgfs-only/inode.c
sudo cp -p vmhgfs.tar vmhgfs.tar.orig
sudo tar cf vmhgfs.tar vmhgfs-only
sudo vmware-config-tools.pl
```